# Need Ajax function - update db without refresh of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need help with one ajax function

This is raw page setup.
Page will contain table with links in this form

....
link - button1 - button2
link - button1 - button2
link - button1 - button2
...

where button1 is for hiding of row, and button2 is for hiding + adds+1 value to that link in db. every link will have unique id that will go with button2, so it would be easy to target it.
So , visitor would click on one of button in a row, row will hide, then he moves to another row....

DB setup:

id - link - .... - nmbOFlikes

My problem is that I dont know Ajax, and it is only solution to update db without need to refresh after every button click.

That page is not static, it is formated by another function that draws data from db
This is simple html page version, so if anyone could help...

So this is javascript without function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button.live").click(function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').hide();
        alert('Link is hidden');
    });
$("button.add").click(function(){
  $(this).parents('tr').hide();
  alert('This link is dead');
  $.post("update_db.php", { id: button_id, increment: true },
   function(data) {
   alert("Link incremented");
 });
```

});
    });

And this is table

```
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
        <td><p>Link 1</p></td>
        <td><button class="live">live</button></td>
        <td><button class="add" id="1">add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>Link 2</p></td>
        <td><button class="live">live</button></td>
        <td><button class="add" id="2">add</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There are a plethora of ajax examples. You can decide wether you want to repeatedly call the refresh, or refreshes once or whatever, but the principal is the same. Ajax is in short, javascript calls some data, which you can then use to assign say the inner html or whatever of some element.. Take a look at examples, and have a try

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't add the value directly to the database, you will post the data to a script first.  I'm not completely clear on what your trying to accomplish but the post function may look something like:

```
$.post("update_database_with_ajax.php", { id: button_id, increment: true },
   function(data) {
     alert("Link incremented");
   });
```

Here is a functional jsFiddle example: [Jquery POST Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GbqJA/3/)

**update_data_With_ajax.php**

```
/** This is an example and should not be used 'as is' **/
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['increment'] ) {

    // Connect to MySQL
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

    if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    // Fetch the values we posted using AJAX
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['id'] );

    //Select your database
    mysql_select_db("my_db", $conn);

    //increment your number of clicks    
    mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET nmbofclicks = nmbofclicks + 1 WHERE id = {$id}");

 }
```

Comment: I've updated the update_data_with_ajax.php section, hope that makes a bit more sense.  Based on your comment below just keep in mind that your using ajax to send **POST** data not **GET**

Comment: I tried this way, but vaalue is not changed in db... Probably I didnt get it right?! :/

Comment: Ok two questions (1) what does update_db.php look like? (2) Where are you grabbing the ID of the button.

I think you need a bit more direction than I've included, let me update it.

Comment: First, update_db.php is exact as your update_data_with_ajax.php
Second, I dont know how to grab id of buttom. Button with class=add is button with target id, so maybe I dont need class for it. When that button is clicked, id of it shoud be grabed, send to update_db.php, and hide that entire row

Comment: Which button are you attaching an event listener too with 'button.dead'?

Comment: event listener is for 2nd button is a row , button class=add. Any ideas mate?

Comment: I've create a fiddle example for you, I think it will help :) http://jsfiddle.net/GbqJA/3/

Comment: Thx mate..But smth is not right :/
1st of all ,I dont need add button, dead button should have id :)
2nd , I dont get any msg like About to update or Link incremented..
3rd, Im using localhost aka Wamp. Is this maybe wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong with using WAMP; is the update_db script in the same directory?  You changed it to use generic permissions right?

Comment: This is the current fiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/GbqJA/18/ does that make sense?

Comment: yes, it is in same directory, and I used my setup (un/pass) for conecting db, changed db-name ,table and row to fit mine. Everything else is as you wrote it up

Comment: Identify the point of failure by running var_dump on $_REQUEST; you can make sure that the variable keys are correct ( $_REQUEST['id'] ) and that the post is successful.  You will need to look in the response part of your developer tools.

Comment: I get now About to...msg , but dont get other msg - Link incremented...Is there an error? The idea for table is awesome too :D

Comment: Alright, so have you used the developer tools to see what the response of the script is?  Also can you define your database schema?

Answer (score 0):

Simple usage of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "serversite.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        // Object of data you will send to serversite.php
    },
    success: function() {
        // everything went ok.
    }
});
```

Comment: OK, I understand that I need to build some page that will process my request for db, so I dont need to refresh every time button is pressed.
All I wanna pass is id of buttom for that page aka. process.php?id=buttom id, and there in process.php I get all done.
But, I still dont know how to code that!!